# Ibm lotus notes : how do I set the column to only show data which matches a specific word

Tags: lotus-notes

Can I sort the data using the @if conditional statement

```
Data := @If(Form = "oneTask"; info_1; Codes);

@If(Data = "Database Details"; 1;0 )
```

Comment: Du you want to "filter" instead of sort? Then your code goes into selection formula of the view, NOT the column formula

Answer (score 2):

You'd change your column formula to

```
Data := @If(Form = "oneTask"; info_1; Codes);

@If(Data = "Database Details"; "Database Details"; "")
```

Column would show "Database Details" only if field info_1/Codes contains "Database Details". Otherwise column would be empty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Knut but this command is still not working as expected I see that it lists all the contents which matches the keyword but then it also lists the other non matching content

Comment: This might happen if fields info_1 or Codes are multi value fields (list of strings). I updated my code. It shows "Database Details" only now and only if fields are containing "Database Details".